# Why is my Flash animation overlaying my div position?

Tags: html, css, flash, fancybox

I am using FancyBox to generate a popup image.

> [FancyBox](http://fancy.klade.lv/) (In case you are curious.)

It pops up a `div` with `z-index: 92;`.

I have a Flash animation running which is far below that `z-index`.

My problem is that in two different Firefox browsers (same versions) I have different results.

In one, everything appears OK. In the other, the Flash animation appears in front of the `div`. I have tried refreshing and restarting the browser but the same issue always occurs.

I know one of the screen shots is from IE but it is only meant as a reference.

What could I be doing wrong?

http://www.my-clock.net/tmp/sreen01.jpg

[alt text http://www.my-clock.net/tmp/sreen02.jpg](http://www.my-clock.net/tmp/sreen02.jpg)

Comment: I tried to scale the first image using an HTML img tag, but it doesn't seem to work. Could you perhaps scale the image as its width destroys the site layout

Comment: Ah, finally it works. Forget to quote width/height inside the tag.

Comment: btw that's why i like to use a mix of tables and divs :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try setting your wmode = transparent on the flash. This will keep flash from laying over top of everything no matter what z-index you set it to.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to paste some of your CSS code at [w3schools TryIt Editor](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_zindex1) to check if it is correct and z-index works as you think.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you need to set the **wmode** parameter separately for IE and other browsers:

```
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" /> <!-- for IE -->
<embed src="images/banner/banner.swf" quality="high" wmode="opaque" ... <!-- for other browsers-->
```

Answer (score 0):

While `wmode=transparent` will work, it causes [quite a performance hit](http://lists.deconcept.com/pipermail/swfobject-deconcept.com/2006-May/000282.html). You'll probably get better results with `wmode=opaque`.

Answer (score 0):

What if you can't change the flash modes because it's a banner from a network like AdSense?

Comment: create a question with that if you wish to know the answer