# jQuery animate layering issue in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-animate

If you hover over the `<img>` the 'hiddenPanel' `<div>` is to appear. This works fine in FF and other browsers, but in IE the `<div>` appears BEHIND the 'content' `<div>`. I've tried z-indexing to no avail. Anyone else having this problem?

(Also, I will not move the code AFTER the 'content' `<div>` for layout reasons)

EDIT: More code; jQuery / HTML / CSS ...

### jQuery

```
    /* Column Left #1 */      
    $('.columnLeft_spec1_panel').hide().css('opacity','0.0');
    $('.columnLeft_spec1').mouseover( function() { $('.columnLeft_spec1_panel').animate({ width: '337px', height: '234px', opacity: 1.0 }, 1250 ); });
    $('.columnLeft_spec1_panel').mouseout( function() { $('.columnLeft_spec1_panel').animate({ width: '1px', height: '1px', opacity: 0.0 }, 1250 ); });
```

### Html

```
<div class="columnLeft">
  <img runat="server" src="~/images/pc_blocks_columnLeft_spec1.gif" class="columnLeft_spec1" alt="" />
  <a runat="server" href="~/" class="columnLeft_spec1_panel">&nbsp;</a>
  <img runat="server" src="~/images/pc_blocks_columnLeft_spec2.gif" class="columnLeft_spec2" alt="" />
  <a runat="server" href="~/" class="columnLeft_spec2_panel">&nbsp;</a>
</div>

<div class="columnRight">
  <img runat="server" src="~/images/pc_blocks_columnRight_spec1.gif" class="columnRight_spec1" alt="" />
  <a runat="server" href="~/" class="columnRight_spec1_panel">&nbsp;</a>
</div>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="main" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

<div class="subnav">
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="subnav" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="leftPanel">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="leftPanel" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  </div>
  <div class="midPanel">
     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="midPanel" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  </div>
  <div class="rightPanel">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="rightPanel" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
    /* CONTENT
    ======================================================================*/
    .content {
      position:relative;
      height:auto; width:800px; _width:795px;
      margin:5px 5px 0px 90px; padding:20px 10px;
      min-height:250px; z-index:0;
      background:#FFF;
    }
    .leftPanel, .midPanel { float:left; }
    .rightPanel { float:left; }

    .content .leftPanel {
      height:auto; width:150px;
    }
    .content .midPanel {
      height:auto; width:375px;
      border-right:solid 1px #78A22F;
      padding:0px 30px 30px 30px;
    }
    .content .rightPanel {
      height:auto; width:180px;
      padding:0px 0px 0px 20px;
    }

    /* COLUMNS
    ======================================================================*/
    .columnLeft, .columnRight {
      height:245px; width:85px;
      background:#EEEEEE;
      margin-top:5px; position:relative;
    }
    .columnLeft {
      float:left; background:url(../images/pc_blocks_columnLeft.gif) no-repeat;
    }
    .columnLeft .columnLeft_spec1 {
      position:absolute;
      top:0px; right:0px;
    }
    .columnLeft .columnLeft_spec1_panel {
      display:none; background:url(../images/pc_columnLeft_spec1.jpg) no-repeat;
      position:absolute; z-index:5;
      left:0px;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide your CSS and jQuery code?

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: check your CSS! Some of the things work in FF good, but in IE you have to redo most of the things because we all know IE is a big problem when it comes to follow the W3C standards.

Here is a demo I made:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
    {
        $(".hoverMe").mouseover(function ()
        {
            $(".hiddenPanel").fadeIn('slow');
        }).mouseout(function ()
        {
            $(".hiddenPanel").fadeOut('slow');
        });
    });
```

And this is the html:

```
<img class="hoverMe" alt="HOVER ME" /> <div class="hiddenPanel" style="display: none; color: blue; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">This is the hidden panel</div> 
    <div class="content" style="color: red;">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</div>
```

You also can try out [this demo](http://www.bogdanconstantinescu.com/jquery/ie-animate.html) of the code above which works in IE as intended.

Comment: Your demo pushes the content down. My panel is supposed to appear over the content and not push anything.

Comment: The HTML changed a bit. Now it doesn't push anything, just comes above the content. This is what you're looking for?

Comment: So I think my issue may be that, since the content is dynamically added in with ASP, it renders AFTER the jQuery and therefore puts it on top somehow. Maybe I'm wrong though ...

Answer (score 0):

Does the content div contain a Flash file?

If it does then you need to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524838/why-is-my-flash-animation-overlaying-my-div-position), it has your solution.

If you could post your jQuery code and the CSS you are using, that would help a lot.